# Is it possible / smart to instantiate a view controller in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that manages my entire view.  Inside this view, I would like to create another four views which each have some button selector functions.  I was wondering if it would be possible/smart for me to create a new View Controller class that has the functionality of these four sub-views and then instantiate these view controllers in the view controller that manages the full view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible. And it is often smart to do so. In your case it sounds like you may want to subclass `UIView` or `UIControl` though.

One of the main reasons to create a view controller is to keep track of the life cycle events of a view. In the view controller methods such as `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`

Creating view controllers works well for cases such as pages and segments, and navigation with `UITabViewController`s and `UINavigationController`s

You can generally just create view controller's and use them, something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let subViewController = AnotherViewController()
        view.addSubview(subViewController.view)
    }
}

class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of the code to use to instantiate a View Controller in another View Controller?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example

Comment: Adding here, do read about child viewController.
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/